# Golang equivalent to Python json.dumps and json.loads

Tags: json, string, go, marshalling, unmarshalling

This is a very weird situation but I need to convert a stringified json to something valid that I can unmarshall with:

```
"{\"hello\": \"hi\"}"
```

I want to be able to unmarshall this into a struct like this:

```
type mystruct struct {
    Hello string `json:"hello,string"`
}
```

I know normally the unmarshall takes bytes but Im trying to convert what I currently get into something structified.
Any suggestions?

Comment: If `str` is a `string` value, what's not to like about `err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(str), &result)`?

Comment: Have you made any attempt? Can you show that attempt? What problem(s) did you encounter?

Comment: Yes I made an effort.  It doesn't work with unmarshal: https://play.golang.org/p/uTBSZz-GPcI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the `encoding/json` package accepts well-formed JSON, in this case the initial JSON that you have has escaped quotes, first you have to unescape them, one way to do this is by using [the `strconv.Unquote` function](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#Unquote), here's a sample snippet:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

type mystruct struct {
    Hello string `json:"hello,omitempty"`
}

func main() {
    var rawJSON []byte = []byte(`"{\"hello\": \"hi\"}"`)

    s, _ := strconv.Unquote(string(rawJSON))

    var val mystruct
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(s), &val); err != nil {
        // handle error
    }

    fmt.Println(s)
    fmt.Println(err)
    fmt.Println(val.Hello)
}
```

Comment: Careful here. strconv.Unquote applies Go escaping rules, which are different from JSON escaping. It's highly unlikely that the input is a quoted Go string literal. Chances are that this is a double-encoded JSON document, in which case you'd just unmarshal twice. Point is, undoing the escaping must consider what the producer of this string did.

Comment: Yeah, the API Im seeing this double quoted is a bug.  But temporarily I need to utilize the API.  I agree that this is very rare and should be careful.  However, I didn't see anyone else who know how to manage such data.  Im curious, how would you "unmarshal twice"?  The unmarshal input would be a byte only right?  The first time I unmarshall it has to be directly to a string? or a byte stream?

Comment: Here's an example of a double-unmarshal: https://play.golang.org/p/5eKwOG5tmfS (I took your example and whacked on it a bit)

Comment: I see.  I didn't realize we could unmarshal to a string.  I assumed it must only be to a struct.  This is also a very good answer.  Different approach than Tristian.  You should post this as a separate anser.